# Sending message from HTTP endpoint to JMS

Tags: java, jms, apache-camel, activemq-classic

I am trying to have a camel route, which would accept a payload on a http endpoint and then write that payload to a JMS queue.

The route that I have so far is below. But an empty message gets delivered to the jms queue. A message gets there, but it has no body.

Heres the route:

```
<route >
    <from uri="jetty:http://0.0.0.0:8050/add/Customer"/>
    <inOnly uri="jms:queue:Q.Customer" />
</route>
```

Heres the payload that I'm sending into to '`http://0.0.0.0:8050/add/Customer`' endpoint:

```
 <Customer xmlns="http://www.openapplications.org/9" xmlns:lw="http://www.org/9">
    <Name>John</Name>
    <Gender>Female</Gender>
 </Customer>
```

Any inputs on why the message body is not being written to the jms queue?
Thanks...

Comment: Does it work if you add a `<convertBodyTo type="java.lang.String"/>` after the `from` step?

Comment: Nope...does not work even after adding 'convertBodyTo'

Comment: Then I don't know. I set up a route like yours, logging the exchange body instead of passing the message on, and POSTed your XML and it worked for me.

Comment: message logs correctly for me as well..When i try to send it further to jms, the body gets emptied.

Comment: That still sounds like the "stream can only be consumed once" issue. You did place the convertBodyTo right after the from, did you not?

Answer (score 0):

Your routes worked as expected. I tested it with following setup:

```
<broker xmlns="http://activemq.apache.org/schema/core" useJmx="true" persistent="false">
    <transportConnectors>
        <transportConnector uri="tcp://localhost:61616" />
    </transportConnectors>
</broker>

<bean id="jms" class="org.apache.activemq.camel.component.ActiveMQComponent">
    <property name="brokerURL" value="failover:tcp://localhost:61616" />
</bean>

<camelContext xmlns="http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring">
    <route >
        <from uri="jetty:http://0.0.0.0:8050/add/Customer"/>
        <inOnly uri="jms:queue:Q.Customer" />
    </route>
    <route>
        <from uri="jms:queue:Q.Customer" />
        <log message="Body: ${body}" />
    </route>
</camelContext>
```

I tested the route using the `org.apache.camel.spring.Main` helper class:

```
Main main = new Main();
main.setApplicationContextUri("META-INF/spring/jms-inout-producer.xml"); // change this
main.start();

final Object body = "<Customer xmlns=\"http://www.openapplications.org/9\" xmlns:lw=\"http://www.org/9\"><Name>John</Name><Gender>Female</Gender></Customer>";

final ProducerTemplate template = main.getCamelTemplate();
template.requestBody("http://localhost:8050/add/Customer", body);
```

This lead to following output:

```
INFO  Body: <Customer xmlns="http://www.openapplications.org/9" xmlns:lw="http://www.org/9"><Name>John</Name><Gender>Female</Gender></Customer>
```