# ActiveMQ : ActiveMQ has their own http endpoint that accepts http request?

Tags: activemq-classic

I have to handle the case when my system is shutdown for accepting every requests and guarantee no data loss. So, I decided to change the way that accept the http request. Now, I am using http gateway in spring integration and jetty http servlet. It can't guarantee about no data loss.

So, my conclusion is..
I saw that ActiveMQ has a Servlet that takes care of the integration between HTTP and the ActiveMQ dispatcher. If I configure activemq HA and activemq receives their own receiver for accepting the http request. So, The activemq can receive every request without missing data. (enqueue)

Below, it's not what I want. It isn't what I want.
[Sending message from HTTP endpoint to JMS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23294816/sending-message-from-http-endpoint-to-jms)

Comment: Is there a question here?  Please edit it so you're actually asking a question you'd like us to answer.

Answer (score 1):

There is a simple way you can post your messsage to a active MQ using an http end- point
here is how you can do it

```
make a POST call to http://*serverIP*:8161/api/message/*NAME_OF_QUEUE*?type=queue
```

and your body should contain  "*YOUR_MESSAGE*"

For more info - http://activemq.apache.org/rest.html